# How to Delete Output of the Processing Tool in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have been developing a processing tool that iterates through polygons, and for each polygon, I perform hydrological processing and call various processing tools such as 'native:clip', 'saga:flowaccumulationtopdown', 'saga:catchmentarea', 'saga:featurestoraster', 'gdal:slope', and so on. The output of these processes in the temporary folder is maxing out my computer's capacity. Therefore, after each iteration, I attempt to delete the corresponding folder.

As you can see, I use two functions for that. In 'tempfiles_mapLayer', I simply add the layer to the QGIS project and remove it because I could not find any other way to delete the file. If I do not do this, I encounter the following error.

> [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
> used by another process:
> 'C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_iBXYLY\bb7c0f6cf3314b3684ee9d7cfff5d430\OUTPUT.tif'

How can I accomplish this in a better way?

Here are the funcs and some of the processing tool I us

```
def delete_subfolders_in_temp():
          temp_folder = QgsProcessingUtils.tempFolder()
          sub_folders_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(temp_folder, '*'))

          for sub_folder in sub_folders_list:
            try:
              shutil.rmtree(sub_folder)
              print("Deleted:", sub_folder)
            except Exception as e:
              pass
              print("Not deleted:", sub_folder, e)

def tempfiles_mapLayer(temp_file_qgslyr, project):

  try:
    project.addMapLayer(temp_file_qgslyr)
    project.removeMapLayer(temp_file_qgslyr)
  except ValueError:
    # print(f'Value Error: {temp_file_qgslyr}')
    pass
  except PermissionError:
    # print(f'PermissionError: {temp_file_qgslyr}')
    pass
  except RuntimeError:
    # print(f'RuntimeError: {temp_file_qgslyr}')
    pass
  delete_subfolders_in_temp()


for index, row in all_records.iterrows():
    try:
        .
        .
        .
        resEZG13 = processing.run("gdal:slope", {
                'INPUT': resEZG2['OUTPUT'],  # rlyr_demClp,
                'BAND': 1,
                'AS_PERCENT': True,
                'ZEVENBERGEN': False,
                'OPTIONS': '',
                'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
        rlyr_demSlp = QgsRasterLayer(resEZG13['OUTPUT'], "rlyr_demSlp", "gdal")
        temp_layer.append(rlyr_demSlp)   
        resEZG12 = processing.run("saga:maximumflowpathlength", {
                'ELEVATION': resEZG3['FILLED'],  # rlyr_demFilled,
                'WEIGHTS': None,
                'DISTANCE': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
                'DIRECTION': 1})  # upstream

        rlyr_demFliessLange = QgsRasterLayer(resEZG12['DISTANCE'], "rlyr_demFliessLange", "gdal")
        temp_layer.append(rlyr_demFliessLange)    

        resEZG8 = processing.run("saga:rastercalculator", {
                'GRIDS': resEZG5['OUTPUT'],  # rlyr_demFAccRecl,
                'XGRIDS': [res9_4['DISTHORZ']],  # rlyr_demFLen
                'FORMUL A': 'a * b',
                'RESAMPLING': 1,  # Method: Nearest Neighbour
                'USE_NODATA': False,
                'TYPE': 7,  # 4 byte floating point number
                'RESULT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
              # print_tempfiles("saga:rastercalculator")
              rlyr_demFLenRidges = QgsRasterLayer(resEZG8['RESULT'], "rlyr_demFLenRidges", "gdal")
              temp_layer.append(rlyr_demFLenRidges)
        .
        .
        .
        .

        for layer in temp_layer:
            tempfiles_mapLayer(layer, project)
    except Exception as e:
        logger(f"ERROR >> {traceback.format_exc()}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can't. QGIS does not release the file handlers of those files while the Processing tool is running.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33641#issuecomment-790622961 suggests a workaround (*modifying* the unneeded files to be tiny) but note the comments below, it might not be the best solution for your specific environment.